# Creating a tuple from a folding expression return values

Tags: c++, c++17

I try using the returning values of DecodeInternal function to create a tuple like this.

```
    std::tuple<Types...> Decode(const uint8_t *bufferBegin)
    {
        uint8_t *offset = (uint8_t *)bufferBegin;
        // (DecodeInternal<Types>(f, &offset), ...);
        return std::make_tuple<Types...>((DecodeInternal<Types>(&offset), ...));
    }
```

But when I compile with this template arguments

```
decoder.Decode<int, float, bool, std::string, std::string>(encoder.GetBuffer().data());
```

I get this error from the compiler

```
In file included from ./borsh-cpp/src/main.cpp:4:
./borsh-cpp/src/BorshCpp.hpp: In instantiation of ‘std::tuple<_Tps ...> BorshDecoder::Decode(const uint8_t*) [with Types = {int, float, bool, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}; uint8_t = unsigned char]’:
./borsh-cpp/src/main.cpp:42:110:   required from here
./borsh-cpp/src/BorshCpp.hpp:244:35: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘int&&’ from expression of type ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’
  244 |   return std::make_tuple<Types...>((DecodeInternal<Types>(f, &offset), ...));
      |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/functional:54,
                 from ./borsh-cpp/src/BorshCpp.hpp:4,
                 from ./borsh-cpp/src/main.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/9/tuple:1470:27: note: in passing argument 1 of ‘constexpr std::tuple<typename std::__decay_and_strip<_Elements>::__type ...> std::make_tuple(_Elements&& ...) [with _Elements = {int, float, bool, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}]’
 1470 |     make_tuple(_Elements&&... __args)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`(DecodeInternal<Types>(&offset), ...)` is a [comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do) whose value is equal to the result of the last expression. Also, you don't need to explicitly specify template arguments for `make_tuple`, so just

```
return std::make_tuple(DecodeInternal<Types>(&offset)...);
```

Comment: This is what I was somehow suspecting from the beginning but the compiler error confused me some how. Maybe, it's caused as the result of the "comma expression" is applied as first argument to the function call i.e. the last type is used for the first argument...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But now I have another problem with the template arguments, because the last arguments is used as the first and screw how the algorithm of my function that depend on the order of arguments

Comment: I faced the same problem, even different behaviour on different compilers. This undefined ordering has nothing to do with the template paramter pack expansion, but with order of evaluation of function parameters, as @nathanoliver pointed out in the answer to my respective question:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/77874556/8603646