# correct order in template parameter pack expansion

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, variadic-templates, parameter-pack

I want to fill a `tuple<Ts...>` from a `vector` of `variant`s. (NB: This question follows up on [Creating a tuple from a folding expression return values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72136219/creating-a-tuple-from-a-folding-expression-return-values) , see 2nd comment to the answer )

Expanding the pack in the template argument list for the `tuple` (the return type) works as expected. But expansion of the pack in the function argument list (of `make_tuple()` in this case) seems to reverse the order of types - when compiled with `gcc`.

Pls consider the following mre (also [on compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Tba6fq5zs)) - after studying cppreference I'd expect `in_order` to work and `reversed` to fail:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

using DATA=std::vector<std::variant<int,double>>;

template <typename... Ts> std::tuple<Ts...> in_order(DATA const &args) {
    try {
        auto arg_iter = args.cbegin();
        return std::make_tuple(std::get<Ts>(*arg_iter++)...);
    } catch(std::bad_variant_access const &e) {
        std::cout << "in order fails\n";
        return std::make_tuple(Ts{0}...);
    }
}

template <typename... Ts> std::tuple<Ts...> reversed(DATA const &args) {
    try {
        auto arg_iter = args.cbegin();
        std::advance(arg_iter,args.size());
        return std::make_tuple(std::get<Ts>(*(--arg_iter))...);
    } catch(std::bad_variant_access const &e) {
        std::cout << "reversed fails\n";
        return std::make_tuple(Ts{0}...);
    }
}

int main(int argc,char **argv) {
    DATA data;
    data.push_back(3.3);
    data.push_back(7);
    auto const &[d0,i0] = in_order<double,int>(data);
    std::cout << "in order: " << typeid(decltype(d0)).name() << d0 << " , " << typeid(decltype(i0)).name() << i0 << "\n";
    auto const &[d1,i1] = reversed<double,int>(data);
    std::cout << "reversed: " << typeid(decltype(d1)).name() << d1 << " , " << typeid(decltype(i1)).name() << i1 << "\n";
}
```

When compiled with `clang` on compiler explorer, the behaviour is exactly as expected. But when using `gcc`, it's the other way around: `in_order` fails while `reversed` returns the desired result. As we use `gcc` in our project, I need `gcc` the behave correctly.

My question is: which behaviour is the correct one,

1. `clang` is correct
2. `gcc` is correct
3. both are correct, it's not defined

Or, phrased slightly different: is one of the compilers buggy in the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
return std::make_tuple(std::get<Ts>(*arg_iter++)...);
```

you are calling a function and the [order of evaluation for function parameters is not specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934904/what-is-the-order-of-evaluation-for-function-arguments) so both compilers are correct.

To get both compilers to do the same thing we can just directly construct the `tuple` from the pack expansion like

```
return std::tuple{std::get<Ts>(*(--arg_iter))...};
```

This works because the order of initializers is specified and goes from left to right. You can see both compilers give the same results in this [live example](https://godbolt.org/z/7457s5jW1).

Comment: Oohhh, so the problem was undefined evaluation order of `arg_iter++` in the parameter list, not the template pack expansion!!! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @kaba Yes, the pack expansion works the same for both compilers, it is the evaluation of the function parameters that is getting you.